# htaccess redirecting subdomain traffic to primary domain when https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I'm having issues reaching one of my subdomains via `https`.

Consider the following domains:

- mydomain.com
- tasks.mydomain.com
- stuff.mydomain.com

Whenever I attempt to go to `https://stuff.mydomain.com`, the files (db, etc) from the primary `mydomain.com` are shown instead of `stuff.mydomain.com`. Hope that makes sense.

My primary domain is using the PHP framework `Yii 1.1.15` with the following `.htaccess` in web root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on


# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does your virtual host config file look like? (i.e. server names, alias, ports, etc) - Also, you may have better luck asking at http://superuser.com/

Comment: I believe it's the default. We are using WHM/cPanel and the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file has never been edited.

Comment: well, there you have it... you need to look into what the current configuration looks like.  In cPanel, I seem to remember there being an option to configure https the same as http... so check around that area. - it looks like http://ServerFault.com might be a better place for this question

Comment: I'll try there, thank you.